# Python print to the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2))
    print(number_1 + number_2)
```

How do I get the `print(number_1 + number_2)` to the same line of `print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is just to use the same call to `print`:

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} =".format(number_1, number_2), number_1 + number_2)
```

Another option (probably the best) is to extend your format string:

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(number_1, number_2, number_1 + number_2))
```

But you can also suppress the newline character that print puts at the end of the line by default:

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2), end="")
    print(number_1 + number_2)
```

Final answer:

```
if operation == "+":
    print(number_1, "+", number_2, "=", number_1 + number_2)
```

All of these versions print the same thing.

Comment: Your first example has an extra sauc space in it. Either remove the trailing space in the format or set `sep=''` to avoid that.

Comment: You could also use sys.write for the first part. It won't append a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the line end element of the print statement in the following way:

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2),end = '')
    print(number_1 + number_2)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f"{number_1} + {number_2} = {number_1 + number_2}")
```

Python 3.6^ is required to use f string, its cool and nice, just an alternative to `.format()` method

Answer (score 0):

if you need two print statements, use:

```
print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2), end=' ')
print(number_1 + number_2)
```

end prints end of line by deafult, but I changed it in here to print a space instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to use;

```
if operation == "+":
    print("{} + {} = ".format(number_1, number_2),number_1 + number_2)
```

or

```
print(f"{number_1} + {number_2} = {number_1 + number_2}")
```